# Handle lots of similar monomorphic classes in a polymorphic way

Tags: kotlin

I've got a library which generates a whole bunch of very similar looking Java classes. For brevity, let's specify something like that in Kotlin:

```
data class A(val commonParam1: String, val commonParam2: String, val specialParam: Int)
data class B(val commonParam1: String, val commonParam2: String, val specialParam: String)
data class C(val commonParam1: String, val commonParam2: String, val specialParam: Boolean)
data class D(val commonParam1: String, val commonParam2: String, val specialParam: Float)
```

Obviously, it would be preferable to generate a single generic class or interface:

```
data class G<T>(val commonParam1: String, val commonParam2: String, val specialParam: T)
```

But the library does not generate that kind of code. I have dozens of these classes, and different places at which they get generated, so it's an *m×n* situation. Unfortunately, these classes do not share a common interface (that I can use.) So the way I see it, there are five options to tackle this problem:

- write all the code that works with any of the generated classes *m×n* times. That's a whole bunch of duplication, but it is not at all sophisticated, and it is safe
- use reflection. The idea behind generating these classes in the first place was increased type safety. Reflection would throw that out of the window again, so it feels counter productive
- use code generation for my own code. It feels like a somewhat heavy-handed approach, and my team has no experience with code generation
- use [ArrowKT typeclasses](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/typeclasses/intro/). [Extension Interfaces](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) would be great, but I might get by with the currently existing hacks. I still have to provide a lot of boiler plate, because I have to provide evidence for my interface for each and every one of these classes
- use an [Arrow-Meta](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow-meta) quasi-quoter, but I don't think I should be using Arrow-Meta in production yet

Do I have other options? Is there a way to abstract over similar looking classes like that?

---

In this concrete case, my Graphql schema has a lot of mutations, which take `MutationInputs` that are all very similar. We don't directly control the shape of the schema. Since each mutation also has its own input and output type, constructing these mutations and interpreting their outputs is a chore with a lot of duplicated code even when I use fragments liberally, since even the code to extract the fragment will have to be duplicated.

This is not usually a problem in Graphql because most of it is done in JS or TS, both of which have duck typing. Kotlin doesn't have duck typing.

Comment: Are the classes just empty data containers?  No methods or logic?  Do they need to be data classes (because you have limitations around data class inheritance)?  These questions matter because they affect the possible solutions.

Comment: They do have some logic/methods, but for the most part, they're data transfer objects.

Comment: ok, I gave some variations of solutions in an answer, along with options for code generation from annotation processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am listing multiple options here, some might be used in combination to re-use code and generate the minimal amount of tedious code.

## Interfaces with Default Implementations

You can use an interface with default implementations of functions to provide the common base:

```
interface CommonDataInterface<T> {
    val commonParam1: String
    val commonParam2: String
    val specialParam: T

    fun foo() { ...implementation here }
    fun bar() { ...implementation here }
    fun zoo(x: T): T { ...implementation here }
}

// concrete variations, using common interface functions implemented above:

data class A(override val commonParam1: String, 
             override val commonParam2: String, 
             override val specialParam: Int) 
             : CommonDataInterface<Int>
data class B(override val commonParam1: String, 
             override val commonParam2: String, 
             override val specialParam: String) 
             : CommonDataInterface<String>
data class C(override val commonParam1: String, 
             override val commonParam2: String, 
             override val specialParam: Boolean) 
             : CommonDataInterface<Boolean>
data class D(override val commonParam1: String, 
             override val commonParam2: String, 
             override val specialParam: Float) 
             : CommonDataInterface<Float>
```

---

## Extend Base Class Using Non Data Classes

Another approach is generic classes that are not data classes:

```
class G<T>(val commonParam1: String, val commonParam2: String, val specialParam: T) { 
    fun foo() { ...implementation here }
    fun bar() { ...implementation here }
    fun zoo(x: T): T { ...implementation here }
}

// concrete variations, using common functions from base class

class A(commonParam1: String, commonParam2: String, specialParam: Int) 
         : G<Int>(commonParam1, commonParam2, specialParam)
class B(commonParam1: String, commonParam2: String, specialParam: String)
         : G<String>(commonParam1, commonParam2, specialParam)
class C(commonParam1: String, commonParam2: String, specialParam: Boolean)
         : G<Boolean>(commonParam1, commonParam2, specialParam)
class D(commonParam1: String, commonParam2: String, specialParam: Float)
         : G<Float>(commonParam1, commonParam2)
```

That does not save much typing and has a lot of redundant parameters.

---

## Use Transparent Delegation of an Interface

An alternative is to use "inheritance by delegation" if you need everything to stay in classes or have multiple different sets of functionality you want to combine (you can implement multiple interfaces and delegate to multiple backing implementations):

```
interface CommonDataInterface {
    val commonParam1: String
    val commonParam2: String

    fun foo() 
    fun bar() 
}

data class CommonData(override val commonParam1: String, 
                      override val commonParam2: String)
                      : CommonDataInterface {
    override fun foo() { ...implementation here  }
    override fun bar() { ...implementation here  }
}

// concrete implementations using common functions via automatic delegation 

data class A(private val common: CommonDataInterface, 
             val specialParam: Int) : CommonDataInterface by common {
    fun zoo(x: Int): Int { ...implementation here using specialParam }
}

data class B(private val common: CommonDataInterface, 
             val specialParam: String) : CommonDataInterface by common {
    fun other(y: String): String { ...implementation here using specialParam }
}

data class C(private val common: CommonDataInterface, 
             val specialParam: Boolean) : CommonDataInterface by common

data class D(private val common: CommonDataInterface, 
             val specialParam: Float) : CommonDataInterface by common
```

But the above isn't allowing `specialParam` to be used by any common function and it would be implemented per specialization.

---

## Generate Permutations of Classes using Annotation Processors

You could write your own annotation processor which is a form of code generation or other compile-time manipulation, add an annotation to your special classes and have the annotation processor generate all of the permutations in the bytecode.  Then it could be baked into your compilation process and magically those additional classes would appear.

You would need to look at how Kotlin does annotation processing and the topic in general somewhere.  Also, post Kotlin 1.4 will probably be a compiler plugin API which could help to write plugins that do similar work.

Some links on annotation processing that show it is not that hard to work with:

- [KAPT - Kotlin annotation processor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html)
- [Hello World of annotation processing in Kotlin](https://medium.com/@MiBLT/hello-world-of-annotation-processing-in-kotlin-3ec0290c1fdd)
- [Idiomatic Kotlin - annotation processor and code generation](https://medium.com/tompee/kotlin-annotation-processor-and-code-generation-58bd7d0d333b)
- [MerryAnnotation - your first annotation processor in Kotlin Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/merryannotation-your-first-annotation-processor-in-kotlin-android-eb3af4ab3402)

---

## Generate Kotlin Code Using a Code Generation Library for Kotlin

A simple way to look at Kotlin code generation is the [KotlinPoet](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet) library.  It is a programmatic way to generate code and makes it easy even for teams with little code generation experience.  This could be used with the variations mentioned previously about how to structure the classes.  It could also be used with annotation processing as your method to trigger code generation during compilation.

Comment: I don't control the base data classes, so can't add interfaces. But I think I might be able to do something along the lines of using code generation to duplicate the base classes and have them implement common interfaces. Maybe, I'll have to take a look at it.

Comment: I wish, Kotlin would feature Duck Typing, would be awesome.